# How to add a GWT module to a dynamically created Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, gwt

What's the best way to handle this scenario ?

- Code wise have I would like to have 2 seperate GWT modules. Modules as defined in this [page](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModules)
- Download both modules in a single download, as a js file.
- Run one of the modules in a dynamically created iframe.

Detailed description:

I have a GWT module called 'embed' which generates embed.nocache.js file.
I have another GWT module called 'widget' which generates widget.nocache.js file.

I add embed.nocache.js to my HTML page. This adds a link called 'widget' in the HTML page.
On click of this link, an iframe (say, widget.html) opens. widget.html has a link to widget.nocache.js. This file gets downloaded, gets executed in the iframe and puts a horizontal panel into the iframe.

Now I need to eliminate a seperate download of widget.nocache.js file.

Say I inherit 'widget' module in embed, it gets compiled and downloaded together. How do I initialise only the 'widget' related javascript in a dynamically created iframe ?

Can creating a custom linker help ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. If you already have an IFrame on your page then just load it into that. The module will run fine so long as it isn't a Cross Site page and belongs to your own domain.

```
Document doc; // iframe document content
final String url_base = GWT.getHostPageBaseURL();
final Frame frame = new Frame(url_base + url_embedded); // your IFrame
frame.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
        doc = IFrameElement.as(frame.getElement()).getContentDocument();

        wrapIFrameContent(); // If you need to wrap any widgets
    }
});
frame.setStyleName("css_style_name");
RootPanel.get("content").add(frame);
```

And that's basically it.

You can embed multiple pages too.

This is just an alternative to Window.Location.assign(url)

Wrap widgets from IFrame pages like this:

```
Button add_module = Button.wrap(doc.getElementById("addmodule")); // button

Element delem = doc.getElementById(id_events_div); // DIV element
events_div = DivElement.as(delem);

events_list = ListBox.wrap(doc.getElementById(id_event_list)); // ListBox
```

Comment: This is useful to load a single module in an iframe. Currently I have 2 GWT modules in a single JS file. Is there a way I can load one of them into an iframe ?

Comment: If the module runs fine by itself then it should load the necessary js source when it's ready to.

Comment: I want to run the different module in an iframe, which is a different scope.